# Script for renaming files - removing dash chars from Android resource files

Tags: bash

The following scripts finds all files in the current directory (recursively) and replaces dash - characters to underscore chars in file names

```
find . -type f -name '*.png' | while read FILE ; do
    newfile="$(echo ${FILE} |sed -e 's/-/_/g')";
    mv "${FILE}" "${newfile}" ;
done
```

given a file in the path that contains dashes, for example, `drawable-hdpi/file-name.png`, the script will try to rename it to `drawable_hdpi/file_name.png` - replacing the dash in the directory name as well as in the file name.

I would like to avoid modifying the directory path, and only rewrite the file name.

Any suggestions on how to modify the `sed` usage to skip the directory path?

Comment: it is a good practice to use lower case variable names to avoid potential conflict with environment variables... and see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/321697/why-is-looping-over-finds-output-bad-practice

Comment: depending on your `find` version and availability of perl based `rename` command, you could do `find . -type f -name '*.png' -exec rename -n 's|[^/]+$|$&=~s/-/_/gr|e' {} +` and remove the dry run `-n` option once you see that command works as intended

Comment: @Sundeep running on osx, which does not come with rename so I'm dependent on mv

Comment: then I would suggest `find . -type f -name '*.png' -exec bash -c 'd=$(dirname "$0"); f=$(basename "$0"); echo mv "$0" "$d/${f//-/_}"' {} \;` instead of using find+while

Comment: @Sundeep looks good :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The shell has some nifty string operators to chop parts of variables. Your shell manual page has all the details. Here's how I would use them:

```
find . -type f -name '*.png' |
while read FILE; do
    dir=${FILE%/*}
    newfile=$(echo "${FILE##*/}" |sed -e 's/-/_/g')
    mv "${FILE}" "${dir}/${newfile}"
done
```

Explanation:

`dir=${FILE%/*}` chops the shortest part from the right that matches the `/*` glob, removing the slash and file name, giving the directory.

`${FILE##*/}` removes the longest part from the left matching `*/`, i.e. leaves just the file name.